# how to convert QMimeType object to string in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

Here I've done a short script to get file mime-type based on the file path.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeDatabase, QFileInfo

a = QMimeDatabase().mimeTypeForFile(QFileInfo("/home/newtron/Documents/testCopy/list.py"))
print(a)
```

It's returning a QMimeType object as data. I need to convert it into a string. What can Ido for that

Comment: Do you mean [`name()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimetype.html#name-prop)?

Comment: yes of course thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had an attribute `name` to show it's mime-type.

eg:

```
print(a.name())
```